# MFC multithreading designing dilemma: how to quit application elegantly?

Tags: mfc

An MFC program(single document with form view) has some sub threads which access some controls on MFC GUI.
The main thread is wished to quit after all sub threads quit.
I tried notifying sub threads to quit and wait them in OnDestroy handler.
However, there is a dilemma over here.
Because sub threads might SendMessage GUI controls while main message loop is blocked in OnDestroy handler. That is a deadlock.

I have an idea to solve this: I hope there could be a way to handle MFC's WM_CLOSE or WM_QUIT and use a custom message like UDM_QUIT which is sent by sub threads to main thread to do the actual quitting, meanwhile I don't wait sub threads to quit in OnDestroy handler. But i'm not an MFC guru and don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Accessing controls from threads other than the owning thread is a bug. You need to fix that bug, instead of trying to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that I can handle main frame's OnClose to realize the idea I mentioned above.